# Simple python port scanner (with questions)

Tags: python

i'm new to python programming and here is a fisrt code i've done

so,here is a port scanner i've done , it works fine on localhost ,
but when i try to scan a website , after waiting 10 minutes there is nothing
what is wrong with my code.

here is the code:

```
from socket import *

print "Simple port scanner"
print "-------------------"
print ""
adress = raw_input("Enter adress (or localhost): ")
ip = gethostbyname(adress)
print adress,"has the IP:",ip
alpha = int(raw_input("Port (min):"))
omega = int(raw_input("Port (max):"))


def scanner(ip,min_port, max_port):
    count = 0
    for ports in range(alpha, omega):
        s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        result = s.connect_ex((ip, ports))
        if(result == 0) :
            print 'Port %d: is OPEN' % (ports,)
            count = count + 1
        s.close()
    print "Scanning finshed !"
    print ""
    print "Found",count,"open ports"           




print ""
print "Beggin to scan..."
scanner(ip,alpha,omega)
```

Here is the output for localhost:

```
    Simple port scanner
-------------------

Enter adress (or localhost): localhost
localhost has the IP: 127.0.0.1
Port (min):0
Port (max):100

Beggin to scan...
Port XX: is OPEN
Port XX: is OPEN
Scanning finshed !

Found 2 open ports
```

and the output for google (for example)
and there is the problem , there is NOTHING :(

```
 Simple port scanner
-------------------

Enter adress (or localhost): google.com
google.com has the IP: 74.125.195.100
Port (min):24
Port (max):82

Beggin to scan...
```

Thank you for helping me .

Answer (score 0):

If you change `s.connect_ex()` to `s.connect()`, an Execption will be raised if an error occurs. connect_ex returns a error value which needs to be interpreted. There are many errors, e.g. timeout or connection refused.

If I test it on my server, many ports are actively refused. So if I print

```
    print "Port %d is closed" % ports
```

I can see that all ports are refused.

The best approach would be to go through the error messages you get with `connect()` and find out how to handle those, especially because you are new to python.

Additionally, you can set a timeout after which your socket gives up on trying to connect.

```
    s.settimeout(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answer Lawrence Benson ,
i have try it with some othe IP's (no more google , but my website and friend website to stay legal) but same error , have you an idea to improve this script ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you,
I have made some changes and now it works :) I have changed ".connect_ex" to ".connect", add try/except, and two settimeouts.

Here is the code again (modified):

```
from socket import *

print "Simple port scanner"
print "-------------------"
print ""
adress = raw_input("Enter adress (or localhost): ")
ip = gethostbyname(adress)
print adress,"has the IP:",ip
alpha = int(raw_input("Port (min):"))
omega = int(raw_input("Port (max):"))


def scanner(ip,alpha, omega):
    count = 0    
    for ports in range(alpha, omega):
        try:
            print "Scanning port :%d" % (ports,)
            s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
            s.settimeout(3)
            s.connect((ip, ports))
            s.settimeout(3)
            print "Port %d: is OPEN" % (ports,)
            count = count + 1
        except:
            print "Port %d is CLOSED" % (ports,)
        s.close()
    print "Scanning finshed !"
    print ""
    print "Found %d open ports" % (count)          




print ""
print "Beggin to scan..."
scanner(ip,alpha,omega)
```

And the output:

```
Enter adress (or localhost): xxx.xxx.org
xxx.xxx.org has the IP: xx.xx.xx.xx
Port (min):440
Port (max):445

Beggin to scan...
Scanning port :440
Port 440 is CLOSED
Scanning port :441
Port 441 is CLOSED
Scanning port :442
Port 442 is CLOSED
Scanning port :443
Port 443: is OPEN
Scanning port :444
Port 444 is CLOSED
Scanning finshed !

Found 1 open ports
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having a function to check the state of a port.

```
#-*-coding:utf8;-*-
#qpy:3
#qpy:console

import socket
import os

# This is used to set a default timeout on socket
# objects.
DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 0.5

# This is used for checking if a call to socket.connect_ex
# was successful.
SUCCESS = 0

def check_port(*host_port, timeout=DEFAULT_TIMEOUT):
    ''' Try to connect to a specified host on a specified port.
    If the connection takes longer then the TIMEOUT we set we assume
    the host is down. If the connection is a success we can safely assume
    the host is up and listing on port x. If the connection fails for any
    other reason we assume the host is down and the port is closed.'''

    # Create and configure the socket.
    sock = socket.socket()
    sock.settimeout(timeout)

    # the SO_REUSEADDR flag tells the kernel to reuse a local 
    # socket in TIME_WAIT state, without waiting for its natural
    # timeout to expire.
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

    # Like connect(address), but return an error indicator instead
    # of raising an exception for errors returned by the C-level connect() 
    # call (other problems, such as “host not found,” can still raise exceptions). 
    # The error indicator is 0 if the operation succeeded, otherwise the value of 
    # the errnovariable. This is useful to support, for example, asynchronous connects.
    connected = sock.connect_ex(host_port) is SUCCESS

    # Mark the socket closed. 
    # The underlying system resource (e.g. a file descriptor)
    # is also closed when all file objects from makefile() are closed.
    # Once that happens, all future operations on the socket object will fail. 
    # The remote end will receive no more data (after queued data is flushed).
    sock.close()

    # return True if port is open or False if port is closed.
    return connected


con = check_port('www.google.com', 83)
print(con)
```